# setting eventlistener from server side

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to set eventlistener from the server side. For that, I created an object, which will be filled with the required data and send to the client side. On the client side the object arrives but I get following error message: **Uncaught TypeError: evLiObj.setEvLi is not a function**. What do I miss? And the other question: As `this` is inside the object, am I right that it is reverenced to the objects id and event?

Would be happy for some help. Thanks!

server side:

```
// creating object on server side
let evLiObj = {
    id: 'ID1',
    event: 'onclick',
    setEvLi: function(){
      let el = document.getElementById(this.id);
      el.addEventListener(this.event, logData(el.id, el.value));
    }
  }
```

client side:

```
// call the function to create the eventlistener
evLiObj.setEvLi();

// function called from the eventlistener
function logData(id, value){
   console.log(id);
   console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: The server code executes on one machine. The client code executes on a totally different machine, far away, in a different OS, a different environment, and not even at the same time. How can you define a variable on one, and expect it to simply be defined on another? :) You need two codebases, and make them talk (with network requests, etc)

Comment: You can't serialize functions in JSON

Comment: So there is no solution to write functions on the server, transfer it to the client side and initialize there. Something like: `var storedFunction = foo.toString();` and on the client side: `var actualFunction = new Function('return ' + storedFunction)()`?